# How to remove the margin between two images?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to set the margin and border to 0,but still not working.

```
<style type="text/css">
img {margin:0;}
</style>
<body>

<img src="/static/btnNext.gif" border="0" />
<img src="/static/btnSave.gif" border="0" />
```

How to make two images stay close to each other?

Comment: it's probably the line return between the 2 buttons that is the problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can eliminate the css for the image and put the image tags on the same line with no space.

```
<img src="/static/btnNext.gif" border="0" /><img src="/static/btnSave.gif" border="0" />
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer in this case as it produces no side-effects (what `float:left` and `display:block` do).

Comment: @jeerose +1, thanks! @Mak: on FF 3.6 and Safari using DOCTYPE your example works perfectly and new lines between images are IGNORED! An exception (as usual) is obvioulsy IE7 (did not try IE8) that show this strange behaviour, and the only workaround seem to be the one suggested by jeerose.

Answer (score 7):

Comment-out the line break between them.

```
   <img src="/static/btnNext.gif" border="0" /><!--
--><img src="/static/btnSave.gif" border="0" />
```

Why? HTML allows as many spaces (both breaking and non) for code formatting, but only displays the first.  In your case, the images being on different lines is being interpreted as a space between them.  The simplest solution is to put them both on one line, but that isn't as readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
img {margin:0; float: left;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, but couldn't find an answer to my problem, first i don't want my images to float left; second, using *diplay:block* is not a good idea because i want them in-line, also *display:block in-line* makes doesn't work.

The SOLUTION is quite easy, take out the "enter" and put your images in the same line. I explain:

WRONG

```
<img src="flower1.jpg"/>
<img src="flower1.jpg"/>
<img src="flower1.jpg"/>
```

OK

```
<img src="flower1.jpg"/><img src="flower1.jpg"/><img src="flower1.jpg"/>
```

So hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what the accepted answer said 5 years prior to this.

Answer (score 0):

this css should stick the images close to eachother without any space, linebreaks or borders between the images...

```
<style type="text/css">
img {margin:0px; padding: 0px; float: left;border:0px}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put each image in a individual div having style float:left. These 2 divs should be enclosed within a parent div which itself is float: left like,

```
<div style="float:left">
<div style="float:left">
<img src="/static/btnNext.gif" border="0" />
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<img src="/static/btnSave.gif" border="0" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces between `img` tags and use css `vertical-align:top`

HTML:

`<img src='http://i.imgur.com/wipljF1.png'/>NoSpaces<img src='http://i.imgur.com/wipljF1.png' class='playerpreviewbig'/>NoSpaces<img src='http://i.imgur.com/wipljF1.png' class='playerpreviewbig'/>`

CSS:

```
img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
vertical-align:top;
}
```